# Undefined symbols, cvSmooth in opencv2.3.1 on mac

Tags: opencv

I am a beginner of Opencv. Recently I came across about problem about cvSmooth. When I tried to compile it using Xcode, the compiler gave me an error saying,
Undefined symbols:
  "_cvSmooth", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Does anyone know what causes this problem? Thank you!

Comment: First, try to compile your source code via command line: `g++ demo.cpp -o demo \`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv\`` If you have OpenCV installed properly on your system, this should work. If it successfully compiles, it means it's just an environment issue and you need to follow what @SSteve said.

Comment: since you're just beginning with opencv, maybe try to avoid the deprecated c-api in general (cv* functions, IplImages, etc) they moved over to c++ already 5 years ago, and so should you ..

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV compiles a number of libraries.  If you're like me and started out with the OpenCV tutorials (I'm using the O'Reilly book) you added `libopencv_core.dylib` and `libopencv_highgui.dylib` which worked up until using the `cvSmooth` function.

Linker errors (undefined symbols) are code for "you haven't linked against all of the necessary libraries and therefore I can't find the routine you've asked for."  They can be easy to find with the `nm` command, sometimes you can help the search by providing the library you think it might be in:

```
joe@macmini:/usr/local/lib [master]
$ nm libopencv_imgproc*|grep cvSmooth
0000000000132a60 T _cvSmooth
0000000000132a60 T _cvSmooth
0000000000132a60 T _cvSmooth
```

Add `libopencv_imgproc.dylib` to your Xcode project and you should be off to the races.

PS:  `_cvSmooth` shows up 3 times because of the soft links against the base library:

```
$ ls -l libopencv_img*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  2063132 Feb 16 17:48 libopencv_imgproc.2.4.8.dylib*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin       29 Feb 16 17:48 libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib@ -> libopencv_imgproc.2.4.8.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin       27 Feb 16 17:48 libopencv_imgproc.dylib@ -> libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you don't link the OpenCV library to your compiled program. Try the instructions for using OpenCV in an Xcode project on the [OpenCV Wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/UsingOpenCVUnderOSX) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

i got the exactly same problem few days ago. but, it's fixed now.

Basically, you need to check three things.
1. Have you set the search path correctly?
on your project "building Settings" tag, you need to set the Header Search Path and Library Search Path to the header's and lib's directory. I installed opencv 2.4 by using MacPort, so the path is /opt/local/include & /opt/local/lib

1. Have you manually add the library?
   Under the Building Phases --> Link Binary with Library tag, you need to add those opencv dylib that you need to use to this place.
2. Have you choose the GCC compiler?
   the default compiler in your Xcode is Apple LLVM compiler, which use c++11 standard. Since opencv 2.4 is not compatible with this standard, you need to switch the compiler to GCC. You can change it under the Building Setting tag

Hope my experience can help you fix the problem ;)